# Subscribe a forkJoin returns an error message

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I'm trying yo detect when all my observable returned their value. Here is how I do it after importing `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';`:

```
    let observables:any[] = [];

    observables.push(this.getValue1().subscribe((value1)=> {
        // Do something with value1
    }));
    observables.push(this.getValue2().subscribe((value2)=> {
        // Do something with value1
    }));

    Observable.forkJoin(observables).subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log('initialized');
        },
        err => console.error(err)
    );
```

my values are returned through `observer.next(valueX);`

I get the following error message: `TypeError: source.subscribe is not a function`. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Here is how I create my `getValues()`

```
getValue1(): any {
    return new Observable(observer => {
        this.asyncFunc(arg1, (err, value1)=> {
            observer.next(value1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing `Observables` to `forkJoin` you are passing `Subscriptions`. As soon as you call `subscribe` on an `Observable` you are telling it you are finished building the pipeline and are ready to start processing, so instead of another `Observable` it returns a cancellation primitive (read: Subscription) instead.

You only need the `subscribe` block once at the end. If you need to do intermediate processing on the values in the `forkJoin` note that it takes an optional selector argument as well.

```
let observables:any[] = [];

observables.push(this.getValue1());
observables.push(this.getValue2());

Observable.forkJoin(observables, ([value1, value2]) => {
  //Do something with value1 and value2
  return [value1, value2];
}).subscribe(
    data => {
        console.log('initialized');
    },
    err => console.error(err)
);
```

**Edit**

Now since `forkJoin` only joins the `Observables` when they complete. You will need to complete the sources (and likely handle any errors as well). Hence `getValue1` should become:

```
getValue1(): any {
    return new Observable(observer => {
        this.asyncFunc(arg1, (err, value1)=> {
            if (err)
              return observer.error(err);

            observer.next(value1);
            observer.complete();
        }
    }
}
```

Note however that there is already an operator available for this called [`bindNodeCallback`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/BoundNodeCallbackObservable.ts)

Which would allow you to simply write:

```
this.getValue1 = Observable.bindNodeCallback(this.asyncFunc);
this.getValue2 = Observable.bindNodeCallback(this.asyncFunc);
```

letting you call these functions in the same way:

```
let observables:any[] = [this.getValue1(), this.getValue2()];
```

As for the second question of how to be able to update on completion. If you use `bindNodeCallback` you can use a secondary stream to update your progress bar.

```
//Lift the length into the stream
Observable.of(observables.length)
          //Create an Observable that emits any time one of the source
          //streams emits
          .flatMap(len => Observable.merge(observables),
           //Compute the percentage completed
                   (len, _, inner, outer) => outer / len * 100)
           //Do your updating
          .subscribe(percentCompleted => /*Update progress bar*/);
```

If you choose to not use `bindNodeCallback` you can do the same thing but you will need to do a bit more leg work because each of your streams is cold, meaning that each `subscribe` results in a new call to `asyncFunc` (`bindNodeCallback` goes hot when called and caches the returned value for new subscribers)

```
//Turns these in to ConnectableObservables
let observables:any[] = [this.getValue1().publishLast(), this.getValue2().publishLast()];

//Set up the other streams
Observable.of(...);

Observable.forkJoin(...);

//Start your Observables
observables.forEach(c => c.connect());
```

Comment: What if I want to detect each time an observable is done as well (a progress bar for example)?

Comment: I've tried your solution but `console.log('initialized)` is never called! I've edited my question to specify the way I create my observables.

Comment: Because you are not calling `complete` on the `Observer`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Even by changing `next()` to `complete()`, `console.log('initialized');` is never called... In addition, can you please explain how to get the progress of the observables (each time one async function is completed, I would like to increase my progress bar)

Comment: See my edit, you need to call `next()` then `complete()`.

Comment: Made it working, thanks! However, I'm not very clear with a couple of things here... I define `this.getValue1 = Observable.bindNodeCallback(this.asyncFunc);` in another module and would like, after my asyncFunc returns its value, to do some things in the other module `this.getValue1 = Observable.bindNodeCallback(this.asyncFunc(arg1, (value1)=> //do something with value1);` The problem here, is that I need to make sure that my progress bar equals 100% only after I'm done processing with value1 in the other module. `flatMap` seems to be called before...any solution using `bindNodeCallback`?

Comment: You would just need to subscribe the result of calling `this.getValue1()`, i.e. `this.getValue1(arg1).subscribe(/*Do something with value1*/);`. For the rest of the question it is getting past the scope of the original question so it might be best to just open a new question.